# Separating array values into multiple arguments

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, sanitization

I have a function I am creating inside of a custom database class. The function is designed to take parameterized SQL, sanitize the input and execute it.

The only issue I am having is with the last uncommented line. I have a variable of type array, but I need to pass each value in the array as a separate argument. How would I go about doing this?

```
function do_query($sql, $values){
    if(!isset($this->connect_error)){
        if(tg_debug == true){
            print "Query Executing! <br />";
        }
        $num_vals = count($values);
        $i = 0;
        $type = "";
        while($i < $num_vals){
            if(is_int($values[$i]) == true)
                $type .= "i";
            elseif(is_string($values[$i]) == true)
                $type .= "s";
            $i++;
        }
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $num_vals){
            // security stuff goes here...
            $values[$i] = $this->escape_string($values[$i]);
            $i++;
        }

        $expr = $this->prepare($sql);
        print_r($values);
        // $values is still an array, extract values and convert to a seperate argument
        $expr->bind_param($type, $value);
        //$expr->execute();

    }
}
```

Example query: `$class->do_query("INSERT INTO`table`(id, value) VALUES (?, ?)", array(3, "This is a test"));`

Comment: Iterate over the 2nd argument with foreach loop and then use the bind_param in the loop then execute after endforeach

Comment: If you mean:
`$expr->bind_param($type);
foreach($values as $val){
 $expr->bind_param($val);
}`

This does not work. I get a Wrong parameter count Warning.

Comment: See the [discussion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073) on php.net on how to use ReflectionClass to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ReflectionMethod class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)

```
...
$bindParamReflection = new \ReflectionMethod($expr, 'bind_param');
$args = $values;
array_unshift($args, $type);
$bindParamReflection->invokeArgs($expr, $args);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$args = $values;
array_unshift($args, $type);
call_user_func_array(array($expr, 'bind_param'), $args);
```

This will be greatly simplified when the [splat operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) is added to the language, which should happen in 5.6:

```
$exp->bind_param($type, ...$values);
```